# RiouxSVN gateway timeout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to connect to an old RiouxSVN repository from a Windows 10 machine with VS Studio 2022 and TortoiseSVN as SVN client, but when I select the Repo Browser option, I'm not asked my credentials (just to accept a SSH certificate) and the client keeps me waiting 'til I have a 'Gateway Timeout' message. I also get that message when using the repo URL in a web browser. Any ideas?

I have tried with several versions both of VS (2017 and 2022) and TortoiseSVN (1.10 and 1.14). I guess is a RiouxSVN issue but I would like to confirm it...

Answer (score 1):

It is a RiouxSVN issue. We've been seeing the same behavior for the past week as well. Right now the site is down for maintenance too.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem on the side of RiouxSVN. Perhaps with [its reverse proxy](https://twitter.com/RiouxSVN/status/1098596570176634881) (the 'gateway' in the error message).

AFAIK, the problem may occur when you make a commit that includes copy, rename, move file operations. Perhaps, some other operations cause this error. But if you desperately need to make a commit, and it has renames, copies, moves, then excluding these operations from commit may help workaround the problem.

Hopefully the problem is going to be resolved soon.

PS I see that @Jose mentions complete inability to access SVN repositories on RiouxSVN, but perhaps these are two separate problems. I hope that my answer is going to help someone anyway.